# Number of π electrons in all trans-2,4,6-octatrienoic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, electrons, lewis-structure

> Sketch the Lewis structure of *all trans-2,4,6-octatrienoic acid*.
>
> (a) Consider the delocalized π electrons. Employ the particle-in-a-box model. Drawing on your knowledge about the occupation of orbitals in atoms what is the highest occupied state? Sketch the occupation of the energy levels with electrons using ↑ and ↓.

I wondered if the electron lone pairs on the oxygen atoms also counted as π electrons since resonance structures exist where these lone pairs can be delocalised over the molecule.

[image: all trans-2,4,6-octatrienoic acid]

If so, how would this correspond to using them to find the length of the conjugated system because wouldn’t that give extra length where there was no double bond?

Comment: No, discard them. Also, are you sure that such resonance structures exist?

Comment: Which oxygen do you mean? The carbonyl oxygen (=O) lone pairs are orthogonal and cannot participate in the resonance. The carboxyl oxygen (-OH) can participate in resonance to some extent, but since the question asks about particle in a box model, you can't really consider that.

Comment: In UV-Vis spectroscopy, these two electron pairs on carbonyl-O and alcohol-O are named *n* electron pairs because these are *not shared* with the extended $\pi$ electron system.